# Automate xjc command to generate Java src files from multiple dtd

Tags: shell, unix, jaxb, dtd, xjc

Am using xjc to generated JAXB based Java source files from individual dtd files...

When trying to use the following command line invocation:

```
xjc -dtd -d . -p com.myapp.jaxb *.dtd
```

I received this error message:

```
parsing a schema...
[ERROR] Too many schema files for this schema language. Compile one file at a time.
unknown location

Failed to parse a schema.
```

Is there a way (via Unix shell script) to auto generate multiple dtd files?

It would be nice if the Unix shell script can iterate through the entire list of dtds in a dir.

Also, would doing this (automating xjc) negatively effect the ObjectFactory class?

Thanks for taking the time to read this...

Comment: maybe use maven jaxb2 plugin

Comment: Thanks MGorgon, why is this marked as -1 ?

Comment: @MGorgon No, won't help. It's still XJC under the hub, so you'll get the same "Too many schema files" error.

Comment: @socal_javaguy -1 (not from me) is probably for "It would be nice if the Unix shell script can iterate through the entire list of dtds in a dir." You're basically saying here "please do my job for me, write me a script".

Answer (score 0):

I normally concatenate DTDs first in one file prior to compilation. For instance, with the `maven-antrun-plugin`:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>concatenate-dtds</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <concat destfile="src/main/resources/ogc/wms/1.1.0/wms_1_1_0.dtd">
                                <fileset dir="src/main/resources/ogc/wms/1.1.0" includes="capabilities*.dtd,exception*.dtd"/>
                            </concat>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <delete dir="${basedir}/target/generated-sources/xjc/WMS_1_1_0"/>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Example from a real project compiling several DTDs:

https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas/blob/master/wms/1.1.0/pom.xml#L43-L71